# Background color of a panel

Tags: java, swing

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package foodmeterproject;

import java.awt.Color;

/**
 *
 * @author al-sany
 */
public class FoodMeterProject {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        FirstFrame frame=new FirstFrame();

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBackground(Color.green);
    }

}
```

I want to change my background of my program. There is a JPanel. I want to color it's background. I use `frame.setBackground(Color.green)`, but it can't change the background. Could you please help me guys ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It works

Comment: great, don't forget to accept this answer :)